# Use dialog to select a folder path?

Tags: php, user-interface, dialog, window

I want to list files of folder. So, I just want to get the folder path. Is there a way to using a dialog window to get the folder path?

Comment: define the dialogue window? what is it?

Comment: just like file upload.Opening a window to choose files.but now I just want to choose the folder not file.

Comment: Do you want a list of files from server side or client side?

Comment: Do you just want a list of folder paths? Or do you want to be able to open files too?

Comment: I want to get the directory path.I let the user to choose which folder's files to be listed. I just want to make a dialogue box to make much better for user to choose which folder or I can just make a input to let user copy and paste folder path.

Comment: following @Stann0rz files that are uploaded or need to be uploaded?